# Java inheritance downcast ClassCastException

Tags: java, inheritance, classcastexception, downcast

given the following code, I have a question:

```
class A{}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B{}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A a1=new A();
        B b = new B();
//        a=b;// ok
//        b=(B)a;// ClassCastException
//        a=(A)a1;  // ok
//        a=a1;  // ok

        a=(B)a1;  // compiles ok, ClassCastException
    }
}
```

My question is with the line in bold. My understanding is that for the code to compile, it just needs to be satisfied that the classes are in the same hierarchy and as a result it may work (up the tree implicit casting, down the tree requires explicit casting). 
Whenever I have come across ClassCastException it is because the reference was pointing to an object up the tree e.g. a ref of type B pointing to an object of type A.

The line in question appears to be a ref of type A pointing to an object of type A. The cast to (B) obviously is what is causing the ClassCastException. Can someone explain please what it does to effect this?

Note: If a1 was pointing at an object of type B then it works (just tested it). So the downcast is legal regarding the compiler and it can be made to execute without an exception if the reference is pointing at an object of the correct type.

By casting the A ref a1 to a B and assigning it to a, it appears that the A ref a no longer expects to refer to an object of type A but a B?

Thanks,
Sean.

PS I know this is a bit unusual, preparation for Java certification. Normally we downcast to the type on the left hand side e.g. b=(B)a; (and I can see why this gives a ClassCastException).

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, exactly.  You are trying to cast an `A` into a `B`, which is not valid, so you get an exception at runtime.

Comment: If a1 was pointing at an object of type B then it works (just tested it). So the downcast is legal regarding the compiler and it can be made to execute without an exception if the reference is pointing at an object of the correct type.

Comment: Am I missing something with that last line? It looks like C/C++. That doesn't compile in Java (as the comment suggests).

Comment: Sorry, the ** were input when puting my q up? Was trying to highlight the line. Removed them now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All B's are A's, by inheritance. But not all A's are B's. This particular instance isn't, hence the runtime exception.

Comment: By casting the A ref a1 to a B and assigning it to a, it appears that the A ref a no longer expects to refer to an object of type A but a B. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Objects have type. When you typecast, the object's knowledge of its own type is checked against the type you're casting it to (essentially the same way that the instanceOf operator works). If it is indeed an instance of the desired type, the cast succeeds and you get an object reference of the appropriate type. If it isn't an instance of the type being cast to, you get a runtime ClassCastException. Your a1 is an instance of A, but is not an instance of A's subclass B, so it cannot be cast to B. But since it _MIGHT_ have been a B, if the variable had been set to something else, this compiles.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. OK, so I should just forget (for the moment) about the reference type on the left hand side and concentrate on the right hand side. The nub of this is : can a reference pointing to an object of type A be cast to an object of type B? Ans: Y at compile time as it MAY work; N at runtime as a B ref can never point to an A object. I was confused by the fact that there was a A reference on the left hand side! But the ClassCastException is generated on the right? Is that accurate?

Comment: Not quite. Any B ref *is* an A ref, and can always be cast that way since B extends A. But only *SOME* A's are B's, so casting a variable of type A (your `a1`) to type B may or may not succeed depending on whether that particular A is or isn't a B. It may be easier if you relabel these as Cat and PersianCat -- all PersianCats are Cats, but only some Cats are PersianCats, and in this particular case it wasn't.

Comment: Assuming the relevant hierarchy: Cat c1 = new PersianCat(); always works as all PersianCats are Cats. Now, Cat c2 = (PersianCat)new Cat(); gives a ClassCastException because I am trying to create a PersianCat reference to refer to a Cat object. This is incorrect as not all Cats are PersianCats i.e. a PersianCat reference cannot point up the hierarchy.

Comment: By George, I think he's got it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to cast a super class reference variable to a sub class type. You cannot do this. Think practical, a super class object cannot contain independent methods (other than the super class' methods) of the sub class.

At run-time you might call a method in the sub class which is certainly not in the super class **object**.

```
class A{
  public void foo(){}
}
class B extends A {
  public void bar(){}
}
```

Now,

```
A a=new A();
B b=(B)a;
b.bar();
```

When you call like this the compiler, will only check whether the method `bar()` existed in the `class B`. That's it. It doesn't care about what is in the 'object' because it is created at runtime.

But at runtime, as said before there is no `bar()` method in the object `a`. `b` is just a reference that is pointing to object **a** but `a` contains only `foo()` not `bar()`

Hope you understood. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks - lovely, simple example. I have tried to summarise in a reply to @keshlam above. If you get a chance, have a look. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you got a better simple explanation than my :)

Comment: Using the same logic, if we try b.foo(); it should works, because "b" is **just a reference that is pointing to object "a" AND "a" contains foo()**

Answer (score 1):

Downcasts are illegal. An A is not a B and therefore you can't cast it to be one. You can cast B to be A, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, the variable `a` is a reference to an object of type A.
The class B extends the class B,
but the relationship between classes A and B can only be described as follows:

1. Class B isa Class A (every object of type B can legally be cast to class A).
2. Class A is-not-a Class B (you can never assign an rvalue of type B to a reference of type A).

This is legal:  `a = (A)b;`  because class B isa class A.

One way to think of it is class B is a superset of class A.

If A is a set that contains (1, 2) and B is a set that contains (1, 2, 3) then B is a superset of A (in java terms: B can be cast to A) but A is not a superset of B (A can not be cast to B).

From a different point of view:

- Socrates was mortal.
- All men are mortal.

Socrates (class B) isa man (class A).

This is an invalid minor assertion:  All men are Socrates.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that legal casts are ruled by the "IS-A" test, why you can compile your code?, because `ClassCastException` is an Unchecked Exception, since extends from `RuntimeException`

ClassCastException ---IS-A--> RuntimeException (Another example of a possible legal cast).

Answer (score 1):

To downcast in Java, and avoid run-time exceptions, use the following code.

```
if (animal instanceof Dog) {
  Dog dogObject = (Dog) animal;
}
```

`Animal` is the parent class and `Dog` is the child class.